# Why my code does not see new images?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, visibility

In my code I refer to an image:

`ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/1b.png");`

It works. Then I add a new image to the directory (images/1a.png) and Java does not see this image! Moreover, I modify the old image (images/1b.png) and Java display the old version of the image (it does not see the modifications). I tried to press "F5". It does note help.

Does anybody knows what happens and how this problem can be solved?

**ADDED**

I even deleted the old image from the directory. And Java still sees it. I use Eclipse. By the way, I did not "clean and rebuild". How can I do it?

**ADDED 2**

As I have already mentioned I had the strange behavior (new images are not seen, the old images are seen even if they are removed from the file system). As people recommended, I clean the project (in eclipse, click "Project" and than "Clean..."). After that, Eclipse stopped to see old removed images. I was happy, finally I hand an expectable behavior. But then I put the old image back to the file system, and cleaned the project again and I still do not see the image. And I get the following error message:

```
at checkgame.GameWindow$12.run(MyWindow.java:1457)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anybody know what is happening?

**ADDED 3**

I have refreshed the project and after that my code started to see the "old" image (that was removed and than put back). But the code still does not see the new image.

Comment: I hope you are cleaning and building the app again

Comment: clean and rebuild your project

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Don't use an IDE until you're comfortable with compiling and building jars from the command line. There are too many things going on behind the scenes that you have no idea of, which result in problem descriptions like *"But the code still does not see the new image."* . Your IDE may have put the images inside the JAR file.  What happens if you run the main class from the command line?

Comment: how do you insert the pictures? If I remember right eclipse runs the tests in a different directory and has to know which files to copy.

Answer (score 2):

Did you clean and rebuild the project after inserting these files? eclipse could still use the old version of your program.

Comment: I use Eclipse. I just change the code, and I see effect of these changes. So, in a way, I use the new version. But I did not do any "clean and rebuild". Maybe it is the reason of my problem. How can I do it?

Comment: @Roman select the project in the Project Explorer, then use  Menu bar -> Project -> Clean... to clean the project.